# jQuery UI show / hide with a slide effect - how to change the slide "back-in" speed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My page contains many OL lists, each showing a selection of links. When each link is clicked, content slides-out to the right. When clicking through each link, the content then slides back-in, then out again.

Here's a Fiddle showing this in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/juxprose/xu3ck/15/

I would like to slow down the "back-in" part of the slide effect, so it matches the speed of the slide-out. You'll see currently it slides back-in very quickly - I'd like to adjust this speed.

Here's the JS part of the code, where the action happens:

```
$('.trg-open.website-title').click(function (e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 $('.website-info').hide();
 $(this).next('.website-info').show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1400);
});
```

Any pointers gratefully appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this instead of hiding it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.trg-open.website-title').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.website-info').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1400);
    $(this).next('.website-info').stop().show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1400);
   });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xu3ck/16/)**

Comment: Thanks, this gives the smoothest effect.

Answer (score 5):

How about `$('.website-info').hide(1400)`? That will hide it with exact same speed as you are showing the stuff.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.trg-open.website-title').click(function (e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 $('.website-info').hide(1400); //You can set a duration-time in millisec ;)
 $(this).next('.website-info').show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1400);
});
```